# eta invariant and spectral flow

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, index-theory, eta-invariant

We know that for a family of first-order self adjoint elliptic (Fredholm) operator $A_t$, for $t\in [0,1]$ we have the formula
$$\eta(A_1)-\eta(A_0)=spfl(A_t)_{t\in[0,1]}+\int^1_0 \omega(s)ds,$$
where $spfl(A_l)$ denotes the spectral flow of this family of operators $A_t$, $\eta(A_t)$ denotes the $\frac12(Tr(A_t(A^2_t))^{-s/2-1/2}\big|_{s=0}+\ker(A_t))$, and $\omega(s)=\frac{d}{dt}\zeta(B_{t,s})\big|_{t=s}$ via the definition of zeta invariant and $B_{t,s}=|A_{s}|+P_{\ker(A_s)}+(t-s)\dot A_s$.

**Q**: Under which condition we could say that $\eta(A_1)-\eta(A_0)=spfl(A_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$? Is there any paper or result about this direction?